# progress bar 100% width with css

Tags: css

I'm trying to create custom progress bar based on this template http://jsfiddle.net/dantetemp/V4uUk/8/. Does someone happen to know how to make it's width 100% of the window and same time keep all the elements and text nicely aligned?

Assigning width to li doesn't look good to me, because I can't get this way the hole progress bar to take 100% width.

```
    li { width: 30%; }
```

And another related question here. How can I set the minimum width for the hole progress bar, so doesn't loose the layout when someone reduces the widow width?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: That jsfiddle css is not real css, it needs a preprocessor

Comment: I think you don't know what a "progress bar" is. That template shows a breadcrumb trail.

Answer (score 1):

first you ve to use:

```
*, *:after, *:before  {
outline: none;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

then you can user the calc property from css

```
width: -webkit-calc(33.3333333% -76px);
    width: -moz-calc(33.3333333% -76px);
    width: calc(33.3333333% -76px);
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/V4uUk/9/
 don't forget to put float left on each li:

```
float:left;
```

for the  minimum width you can use

```
min-width:600px;
```

i hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when I want something to be a certain width, I put it into a div. So for example (I'm not sure if it'll work for you or not) you could have

```
<div id steps>
<ol class="steps">
    <li class="step1"><span>Estimate</span>

    </li>
    <li class="step2 current"><span>Delivery</span>

    </li>
    <li class="step3"><span>Payment</span>

    </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

and then in your CSS

```
#steps {
width:100%;
}
```

It usually works for me but then again it might work because I have something else in my code. If it doesn't work straight away then I could add the code that I use as well.